# Recognising Missing Values compared to previous days and creating new dataframe, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':   {0:'2020-04-01', 1:'2020-04-01', 2:'2020-04-01', 
                              3:'2020-04-02', 4:'2020-04-02', 
                              5:'2020-04-03', 6:'2020-04-03', 7:'2020-04-03'},
                    'Name':  {0:'AA', 1:'BB', 2:'CC', 
                              3:'AA', 4:'BB',  
                              5:'AA', 6:'BB', 7:'CC'},
                    'Weight':{0:1, 1:3, 2:6, 
                              3:1, 4:4, 
                              5:2, 6:5, 7:7}})
df=df.set_index(['Date'])
```

For each unique date in df.index - I would like to compare the Name columns to those present for the previous date, and if a name is missing, add a value of 0 to the weight column

For example..How would I recognise that 2020-04-02 was missing a row for 'CC' and insert a weight of 0 for this row.

Thereby achieving a DataFrame that looks like this...

|  | Name | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-01 | AA | 1 |
| 2020-04-01 | BB | 3 |
| 2020-04-01 | CC | 6 |
| 2020-04-02 | AA | 1 |
| 2020-04-02 | BB | 4 |
| 2020-04-02 | CC | 0 |
| 2020-04-03 | AA | 2 |
| 2020-04-03 | BB | 5 |
| 2020-04-03 | CC | 7 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Name` to `index`, then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with add `0` with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for original format of `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.set_index('Name', append=True).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index(level=1)
print (df)
           Name  Weight
Date                   
2020-04-01   AA       1
2020-04-01   BB       3
2020-04-01   CC       6
2020-04-02   AA       1
2020-04-02   BB       4
2020-04-02   CC       0
2020-04-03   AA       2
2020-04-03   BB       5
2020-04-03   CC       7
```